# How do you synchronously load a script from another directory via an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I often need to load other javascript files via ajax, so at the beginning I used the standard function jQuery provides for script loading:

```
$.getScript('script_name.js',callback_function());
```

But this didn't work out, since $.getScript is asynchronous (the jQuery API for $.ajax says 'async' is set to true by default; topic is discussed in the comments of the API for $.getScript: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). So I wrote this function, as provided by someone in the comments of the API page linked above:

```
load:function(script,callback){

    jQuery.ajax({

        async:false,

        type:'GET',

        url:script,

        data:null,

        success:callback,

        dataType:'script'

    });

},
```

This seemed to work well, so I went on, but I recently noticed, that this only works for scripts in the same directory, eg. calling myObj.load('test.js') works well, but calling myObj.load('test/test.js') doesn't work at all.

It feels like I'm missing something obvious, but I didn't manage to find the problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update: See the comment stream below, it's nothing to do with jQuery, it's a file permissions problem on the server.**

---

**Original answer**:

Do you get any errors from the browser? For instance, in Chrome or Safari, if you open the Dev Tools and look at the Console tab, does it show errors? Or in Firefox, install Firebug and check in Firebug's console. Or in IE, use the free version of VS.Net... Something should be complaining to you about something.

You can also get more information from your code itself by supplying an `error` function rather than assuming success:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    async:false,
    type:'GET',
    url:script,
    data:null,
    success:callback,
    dataType:'script',
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Look at the `textStatus` and/or `errorThrown` properties.
    }
});
```

**Update**: You've said you see `textStatus` = 'error' and `errorThrown` = undefined. Very strange. Does the **same** script work if you move it so it's not on a subpath? I wonder if the subpath is a red herring, and the real problem is a syntax error in the script.

---

**Off-topic**: Does it *really* have to be synchronous? You can't just poll for a symbol to appear? It's just that synchronous ajax requests **really** trash the user experience. In many browsers, not just your own page but **all** pages lock up during the request.

Here's what I mean by polling: Suppose I wanted to load jQuery asynchronously from JavaScript:

```
function loadScript(url, symbol, callback) {
    var script, expire;

    // Already there?
    if (window[symbol]) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback('already loaded');
        }, 0);
    }

    // Determine when to give up
    expire = new Date().getTime() + 20000; // 20 seconds

    // Load the script
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    // Start looking for the symbol to appear, yielding as
    // briefly as the browser will let us.
    setTimeout(lookForSymbol, 0);

    // Our symbol-checking function
    function lookForSymbol() {
        if (window[symbol]) {
            // There's the symbol, we're done
            callback('success');
        }
        else if (new Date().getTime() > expire) {
            // Timed out, tell the callback
            callback('timeout');
        }
        else {
            // Schedule the next check
            setTimeout(lookForSymbol, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Load jQuery:
loadScript("path/to/jquery.min.js", "jQuery", function(result) {
    // Look at 'result'
});
```

Comment: The error function didn't help - textStatus is set to 'error' and errorThrown is undefined.

Comment: @Alex: Very strange indeed. BTW, I've added a huge off-topic comment. :-) Re your actual problem, does **the same script** work if you move it so it's not on a subpath? I wonder if the subpath is a red herring, and the real problem is a syntax error in the script.

Comment: Firebug helped though, the requests fail because of a 403 error! I'm on a local server I installed on my Ubuntu, I don't know how to solve this?

Concerning the offtopic question: Well, I want to execute functions from the loaded script once it is loaded, and with $.getScript(script_url,function_from_the_loaded_script()); it didn't work.

Comment: @Alex: The functions you wanted to execute would be the symbol to look for in the async polling version.

Comment: @Alex: The 403 sounds like a server setup problem; can you see the script if you type its full path into the browser window? There shouldn't be any path aspect to the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) or anything like that. I just tried it and it worked fine.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Nah, I can't see the script when I enter the path into the browser window... I'm quite new to Linux, and when I set up the server I used chown and chmod until I could edit the files etc. Didn't notice you can't access those files through the browser...

Comment: @Alex: Ah, okay, so that's what the problem is then. You'll want to see what user your web server is running as, and make sure that user has read access to the subdirectory entry and the files within it.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: OK I managed to change the user rights, everything works fine now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you. It really helped. I added "return;" after each callback though just in case.

Answer (score 17):

You can set ajax calls to be synchronous by default using [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/). This is how it looks like:

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
$.getScript('script_name.js', callback_function);
```

If you need asynchronous calls again, just enable it with:

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:true});
```

Comment: Setting the ajax mode to sync works for me, but important: if you pass a callback function `callback_function()`, leave out the brackets. Otherwise the return value of the function is passed and `callback_function` ins executed *before* `getScript()`

Comment: Using `$.ajaxSetup` is not recommended - see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/. It's not a good idea to change ajax calls' `async` attribute default. `$.Getscript` is shorthand for `$.ajax`, so you can do: `$.ajax({ url: url, dataType: "script", async: true })` - works for me.