# jQuery - call functions within a file loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, promise

Please see example below. How do I call my function from within the loaded file?

Here is my external file, loaded with ajax:

```
// some-file-name.js
var api = {
    method1: function() {
        // doStuff here
    }
}
```

Here I am loading the file and hopefully invoking some function from the new methods provided:

```
// load script and do stuff with it when done
$.when(
   $.getScript("some-file-name.js"), 
   $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
       $(deferred.resolve);
})).done(function() {
    // how to call api.method1() when api.method1() gives me undefined? 

});
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: This is a [FAQ](https://www.google.nl/search?q=load+jsfile+with+ajax)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: How do you synchronously load a script from another directory via an ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539740/jquery-how-do-you-synchronously-load-a-script-from-another-directory-via-an-aja)

Comment: @mplungjan - I can load the scripts OK, but how do I call its methods?

Comment: @mplungjan: Rather a duplicate of [jquery .getscript() callback when script is fully loaded and executed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565365/jquery-getscript-callback-when-script-is-fully-loaded-and-executed) @ User789: You should offer a bounty there and close this question.

Comment: Yeah I was on the phone - click the word FAQ in my first comment

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1. $.getScript returns a Promise, no need for custom deferred
// 2. access your response. The Promise passes the response to the 
//    success handler parameter

$.when(
   $.get("some-file-name.js"), // 1
).done(
    function(api) {  // 2
      console.log(api.method1);
    }
});
```

Comment: -1: a) the custom deferred was used to wait for DOM ready, nothing else b) as stated, the callback does not work. The script might not yet have been executed.

Comment: Oh, I have a very good idea. I even can read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/): "*The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed*" If you know more, please tell us.

Comment: a) wrap the statement in a $(document).ready({  }); b) $.getScript will return the script and execute it immediately, maybe with your requirement you should use $.get instead

Comment: a) Which statement, the `console.log`? Yes, that could work as well, but there's nothing wrong with the OP's use of `deferred`. Btw, if you know that `$.ajax` returns a promise, `$.when` is superfluous. b) How would `$.get` help here? Wouldn't it *not* execute the script, so that `api.method` fails for sure?

Comment: a) Yes $.ajax returns a promise, so yes technically you don't need $.when, i was following the syntax in your example. You would use $.when if you want to make multiple asynchronous calls

``$(document).ready(function() {
 $.get("some-file-name.js").done(function(api) {
  // access your file data in here,
  // try console.logging it so you can prove it exists
  api.method1();
 });
});``

Comment: Please notice it's not my question :-) And No, in that snippet the ajax request would only start after DOM ready, which is not the intended behaviour. You could however do
`$.get("…").done(function(resp) {
    $(function() {
        // do whatever we want
        api.method1();
    });
})`